# Implementing Spring Transactions with JAX-RS and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, cxf, jax-rs, spring-transactions

### Background

I am trying to implement a RESTful web service using Apache-CXF that interacts with a database to do some CRUD operations via Hibernate.  The web service consumes and produces JSON formatted objects using the Jackson JAX-RS Provider.

I am currently receiving a *"failed to lazily initialize a collection... no session or session was closed"* exception that is bubbling up from the Jackson provider when it attempts to serialize the response object.

I assumed that if I marked the service method with `@Transactional` that the session would be available to the Jackson provider when it serialized the response, but that does not appear to be the case.

### Question

How do I get the hibernate session to be available while Jackson is walking the object during serialization?

### What I've Tried

#### Spring Configuration

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.db.cif.mapper" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.db.cif.mapper.repository" />
<context:annotation-config />

<tx:jta-transaction-manager>
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</tx:jta-transaction-manager>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="cifmapper" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- JAX-RS Configuration -->
<jaxrs:server id="mappingService" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="mappingServiceBean" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="mappingServiceBean" class="com.db.cif.mapper.MappingService" />

<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
```

#### Service Bean

```
@Service("mappingService")
@Transactional
public class MappingService 
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MappingService.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mappingRepository")
    private MappingRepository mappingRepository;

    @GET
    @Path("/collections/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Collection getCollection(@PathParam("id") String id)
    {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            logger.debug(String.format("Invoked getCollection, Collection id: %s", id));
        }

        return this.mappingRepository.getCollection(id);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/collections/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addCollection(Collection collection)
    {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            logger.debug(String.format("Invoked addCollection, Collection: %s", collection));
        }

        this.mappingRepository.createCollection(collection);

        return Response.ok(collection).build();
    }
}
```

#### Collection Bean

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "CIFMAPPER", name = "COLLECTION")
public class Collection implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1579878442412232635L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "SRC_ENDPT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long sourceEndpointId;

    @Column(name = "DEST_ENDPT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long destinationEndpointId;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "START_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "END_DATE")
    private Date endDate;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SRC_ENDPT_ID")
    private Endpoint source;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEST_ENDPT_ID")
    private Endpoint destination;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "collection", targetEntity = MappingGroup.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<MappingGroup> mappingGroups;

//Getters and Setters Removed For Brevity
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I believe there is a way to make that work (using a `Filter` or intercepetor that opens and closes the session), I think the right answer is: don't have lazy collections and proxies. Configure your mappings so that you don't have lazy collections.

An alternative approach is to manually initialize them. This is often combined with DTOs - objects with a similar structure to the entities that are used as responses to other components (so that you are not directly exposing entities). So your methods return `OrderDTO` rather than `Order`, where the DTO contains as many fields as you need to return to the caller. You manually transfer the values from the entity to the DTO.